# TextField, Labels and ComboBox INSIDE Drop Down Pane in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Java Swing: I recently started learning Swing and I want to add several labels, one button, and three combo box INSIDE A Drop Down Pane! When the user clicks the drop down pane, you can see labels, textfields and comboboxes which will contain the values and when the users clicks drop down pane again, then all the textfields, labels etc are hidden. Is it possible and if yes then could you please help me out (code would be very much appreciated). If you did not understand the design then please visit emirates.com and click on 'Book a Flight'! I'll be trying to implement that type of design

Comment: We are not here to do your entire assignment for you. Post what you have tried and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a multi-row data display object, and you want multiple interactable components on the row, don't use the wrong tool, a JComboBox, for this. Use a better tool: a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: *"Use a better tool: a JTable."* I thought a `JTree` would be better for 'combos within combo' but am voting to close as 'too broad' given the OP has invited us to do their work for them.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: perhaps, it's not all that clear to me, which is one reason I made the answer a community wiki.

Comment: *"it's not all that clear to me"* Same here. That's why I added 'thought' & made it a comment. Mind you, I did not devote great deal of thought to it, given the laziness apparent in the question. ;)